# How can I add a custom view on the large title view of UINavigationBar introduced in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I want to add a custom subview on the large title view of UINavigationBar as App Store is doing in iOS 11. ("user icon" on right side)

We can access the traditional navigation bar area via UINavigationItem.titleView, but it seems that there is no API to access large title view area.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/

I confirmed the name is "_UINavigationBarLargeTitleView" using View Hierarchy Debugger.
Can I add a custom view on it?

Comment: You can also use title view of navigation bar and change height of navigation bar too

Comment: You means I need to make a subclass of UINavigationBar?

Comment: No need to subclass, setting the titleView property with your custom subview would be enough

Comment: I know we can customize the traditional title area with titleView. What I wanna customize is not titleView but "Large Title Area" in iOS11 UI. I'm sorry I cannot add any images because of reputation... https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwiH76vemeDWAhUDbrwKHVHjAZQQjxwIAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fplay%2Fwwdc2017%2F204%2F&psig=AOvVaw3AirkXUpZlc8uIBOenV7jV&ust=1507523732635742

Answer (score 8):

Solution relying on the subview order of the large title label instead of its private class name, to keep it compliant with AppStore guidelines.

```
class CustomLargeTitleNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            for subview in subviews {
                if let largeTitleLabel = subview.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UILabel }) as? UILabel {
                    let largeTitleView = subview
                    print("largeTitleView:", largeTitleView)
                    print("largeTitleLabel:", largeTitleLabel)
                    // you may customize the largeTitleView and largeTitleLabel here
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that this solution does not work when using didMoveToSuperview, how did you make this work out with this lifecycle?

Comment: @AmadeuCavalcanteFilho When you say "_does not work_", it's possibly specific to your case, no? Because according to the votes, it did help myself + 5 other people. So I'd recommend to create a minimum reproducible case, specify the device, iOS version and Xcode version, describe precisely what doesn't work (no logs? wrong size? only when rotating? etc.) and post it in a new Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t saw your question early. I was trying to use the snippet with SwiftUI, I don’t have the piece of code that wasn’t working, but I assume it was my mistake and the different life cycle of SwiftUI that was messing with the expected behaviour. Sorry again

Comment: OK, then it may be worth asking a new question specifically for SwiftUI, which has indeed a different lifecycle than UIKit as far as I know. One obvious difference is that SwiftUI is iOS 13+, while the present question is iOS 11+.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in iOS 13... You'll have to override layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it should be more or less like that, based on this article.https://qiita.com/KikurageChan/items/4152c2d8ac89c601a054

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            let stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)
            if stringFromClass.contains("UINavigationBarLargeTitleView") {
                //subview.frame.size.height = 30
                // Custom view
                subview.addSub.....

            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

CustomNavigationBar

Comment: Does this passes AppStore review?

Comment: @RichardTopchiy did you pass appStore review with that?

Comment: can you share please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP would want to implement this using a public API. This solution is hacky, and a kickback from Apple is highly likely. 

As it stands, there is no public API for adding any custom view on top of the UINavigationBarLargeTitleView. We can only modify the content of the label that lives within.